# My toolbar not displaying

Tags: android

I want to add custom action bar to my app here is my code below

I tried using different methods, every time I failed.

My homepage.java code:

```
package com.mimoh.kulkarni.mimoh;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class homepage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button simpleq,toughq,seeapp,rateapp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
//        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.homepage_titlebar);


        simpleq = (Button)findViewById(R.id.simplequestions);
        toughq = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toughquestion);
        seeapp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.seemyotherapp);
        rateapp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rateapp);

        simpleq.setOnClickListener(this);
        toughq.setOnClickListener(this);
        seeapp.setOnClickListener(this);
        rateapp.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.simplequestions:
                Intent i = new Intent(homepage.this,simple_questions.class);
                startActivity(i);

                break;

            case R.id.toughquestion:
                Intent j = new Intent(this,tough_questions.class);
                startActivity(j);

                break;

            case R.id.seemyotherapp:
                // Intent k = new Intent(this,simple_questions.class);
                //startActivity(k);

                break;

            case R.id.rateapp:
                try {

                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
                    Intent l = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    startActivity(l);
                }catch (ActivityNotFoundException n){
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+getPackageName());
                    Intent l = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
                    startActivity(l);
                }

                break;
        }

    }
}
```

My manifest xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mimoh.kulkarni.mimoh">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".homepage">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".simple_questions"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".tough_questions"></activity>
</application>
```

activity_homepage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/homepagelayout"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <!--app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"-->
        <!--app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"-->

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/simplequestions"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:text="Simple Questions" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toughquestion"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/simplequestions"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:text="Tough Questions" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/seemyotherapp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toughquestion"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:text="See My Other Apps" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rateapp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/seemyotherapp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:text="Rate App" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

my_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:title="Settings"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Screenshot:

[Screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBDYQ.jpg)

What should I do?

Comment: try to set the toolbar height as .. `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`

Comment: still same output

Answer (score 0):

You are using Relative Layout. Your toolbar should be at the top in the parent.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/homepagelayout"
  android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <!--app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"-->
    <!--app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"-->

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


  <Button
    android:id="@+id/simplequestions"
    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:text="Simple Questions" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/toughquestion"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/simplequestions"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:text="Tough Questions" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/seemyotherapp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/toughquestion"
    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:text="See My Other Apps" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/rateapp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/seemyotherapp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:text="Rate App" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: still same output

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried to achieve what you're asking:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
View myToolBar= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myToolbar, null);
toolbar.addView(myToolBar);
```

Beside this you can also add your view to the toolbar xml.

Comment: if applied app crashes

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mimoh.kulkarni.mimoh/com.mimoh.kulkarni.mimoh.homepage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference